# Identifying person using optical flow and clustering?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, opticalflow

So I am using matlab and I've managed to modify one of their examples so that I can now plot the flow lines as people walk below (Camera is above a door).
I use Lucas-Kanade optical flow and the computer vision toolbox.

The lines are defined like so, I also defined the tracked points. These tracked points include cases where the original points haven't changed and so the real(tmp(:)) in this case will be zero and those points will be the same as the orgininally identified feature points.

```
vel_Lines = [Y(:)   X(:)   Y(:)+real(tmp(:))   X(:)+imag(tmp(:))];
allTrackedPoints = [Y(:)+real(tmp(:))   X(:)+imag(tmp(:))];
```

My question is how can I JUST get the points which have successfully been tracked a certain distance? I want to somehow only retain values which the change is large enough.

I'm not great with Matlab's syntax so was hoping this would be easy for someone.

I want to get the points that were successfuly tracked pertaining to the motion, then cluster these points to determine how many people, and then tracked these sets of points using a multiple object tracker.

Comment: Some more code to illustrate your point would be nice.  It would help me to create a solution by just modifying your code rather than having to write things from scratch. However, the easiest thing would be to save the optical flow vectors from the previous frame and do a difference calculation and see if the distance has exceeded a certain amount.  The clustering should be easy. You'd place all points in a list, iterate through each one and collect those points that are a certain distance away from the point then remove them from the list. This will be problematic when you have people nearby.

Comment: Thanks!

Sure, hoping to identify the objects as the walk beneath the door before they get to close to one another.

Comment: Thanks!
Could I email you the code then? I can't fit it on here. The tracking won't be a problem, even with multiple objects, its just identifying the people first (i found background subtraction and blobbing weren't working well and so resorted to this approach). I can also share the videos and stuff via google drive?

Answer (score 0):

If your camera is not moving, then background subtraction may work better for you than optical flow. See [this example.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html)

You can also use the `vision.PeopleDetector` object to detect people. See [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/tracking-pedestrians-from-a-moving-car.html).

If you insist on using optical flow, try the [Fareneback optical flow algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/opticalflowfarneback-class.html), available as of R2015b release.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually been able to obtain a binary image by averaging the flow vectors and then putting the result through a median filter to reduce the noise.
WOuld still like to know how one could cluster the points into the optimal amount of clusters.

FOr example, I am able to get a matrix of points ([x y]) which are the good points-i.e. represent the people BUT i have no clue how to cluster them based on their position in order to separate them into the different people. K-means clustering requires a value of k as an input - but thats what im trying to find out? silleoutes?